# May i known about vCenter Configuration of VMs automatic startup and shutdown configuration delay time different

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-esx, automation

Please May I known ..vCenter already Installed on ESXi 5.0 and already installed VMs on vCenter .. in ESX host configuration=>VMs Startup/Shutdown=>properties=>System setting..
Default Startup delay time and Default Shutdown delay time are work for each VM?
mean (e.g) five VMs in there..Default Shutdown delay time are 30 seconds set..one VM shutdown after 30 seconds other one other VM are shutdown? another mean is all VMs are shutdown simultaneously or one VM shutdown and wait delay time after other VM shutdown?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Your VMs will shut down and start up one-at-a-time using this setting, not simultaneously.